php gdimage image montage poor quality issues
found some code on here at PHP - Create one image from images, the code works however, when I look at the output the edges of each image are extremely low quality (blocky).
Here is the code I'm using, converted the original for webp images.
$images = array(
    "image1.webp",
    "image2.webp"
);
$number_of_images = count($images);

$priority = "columns"; // also "rows"

if ($priority == "rows") {
  $rows = 3;
  $columns = $number_of_images/$rows;
  $columns = (int) $columns; // typecast to int. and makes sure grid is even
} elseif ($priority == "columns") {
  $columns = 1;
  $rows = $number_of_images/$columns;
  $rows = (int) $rows; // typecast to int. and makes sure grid is even
}
$width = 1000; // image width
$height = 406; // image height

$background = imagecreatetruecolor(($width*$columns), ($height*$rows)); // setting canvas size

$output_image = $background;

// Creating image objects
$image_objects = array();
for($i = 0; $i < ($rows * $columns); $i++){
  $image_objects[$i] = imagecreatefromwebp($images[$i]);
}

// Merge Images
$step = 0;
for($x = 0; $x < $columns; $x++) {
  for($y = 0; $y < $rows; $y++) {
    imagecopymerge($output_image, $image_objects[$step], ($width * $x), ($height * $y), 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);
    $step++; // steps through the $image_objects array
  }
}

imagewebp($output_image, "test.webp");
imagedestroy($output_image);

print "<div><img src='test.webp' /></div>";

Here is the output...

I have no idea why the image is rendered so badly just at the edges.
Should note that the original images are webp format and have transparency.
Any help would be appreciated.
Tried with various file formats, different functions

Are the two original webp images are also of width=1000, height=406 ??

is there an alpha channel? what is the input? [mre] requires data.


I have no idea why the image is rendered so badly just at the edges.

Please double check the original input images, if they show the same, it is the input quality. If the input is already of low quality, you can not magically have a better quality in the output of its later processing.

TIP: What you call blocky and at the edges of the image (better: shape) and what you would like to prevent, is that you would like to have anti-aliasing. This is often the point when resizing an image.

NOTE: If you use an image which has transparency, it are actually multiple images, one with image data (the picture) and one with the display image data (the mask). Depending on what you would like to do with the overall image data, you have to keep this in mind to be able to differentiate if you require this.

